# Setting all points of a given ListPlot with a given color in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I make it such that plotting the following function

```
ListPointPlot3D[points, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]];
```

the points I see are green or yellow, for instance, instead of the typical dark blue ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** I give you below two possible solutions in a context related [to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221633/making-plots-that-also-show-up-points-dots-for-specific-coordinates). Nevertheless, please note that @Yaroslav's code is much better.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;

t = Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point@
     Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}], 1]}];

b = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   ColorFunction -> "MintColors"];
Show[{b, t}]
```

[image]

Or

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
points = Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}], 
   1];
a = ListPointPlot3D[points, 
   PlotStyle -> Table[{Red, PointSize[0.05]}, {Length@t}]];
b = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   ColorFunction -> "MintColors"];
Show[{b, a}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Directive` to combine styles, ie

```
ListPointPlot3D[points,  PlotStyle -> Directive[{PointSize[0.05], Green}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find the following approach useful, as it allows me to
manipulate the plot symbol (PlotMarkers does not seem to work with ListPointPlot3D,
at least in Mathematica 7) [originally suggested by Jens-Peer Kuska]:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}}]/.Point[xy_]:>(Style[Text["\[FilledUpTriangle]",#],Red,FontSize-> 20]&/@xy)
```